# .net 3.5:how to implement calculate crc32 for data using dot net 3.5 api?

Tags: java, .net, crc32

how to implement calculate crc32 for data using dot net 3.5 api.I have done the same in java with following code.

```
   public static String getMAC (byte [] value) {  
    java.util.zip.CRC32 crc32 = new java.util.zip.CRC32 ();
    crc32.update(value);
    long newCRC = crc32.getValue();
    String crcString = Long.toHexString(newCRC);
    try {
        crcString = ISOUtil.padleft(Long.toHexString(newCRC), 8, '0');
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (ISOConstantsLibrary.DEBUG) System.out.println("for hex string: " + ISOUtil.hexString(value) + "\nmac" + crcString);        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET FCL doesn't provide a class like java.util.zip.CRC32 so you have to roll your own. It's not tough, there's some decent examples out there:

[Example 1](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net)
[Example 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/01/14/free-hash-a-reusable-crc-32-hashalgorithm-implementation-for-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard CRC32 algorithm in .NET library. You can use other implementations like [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crc32.NET/). Also, if there are no specific requirements to use Crc32 (e.g. you just need to calculate checksum for checking integrity), I recommend to use [Crc32C](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crc32C.NET/). This algorithm can be performed on modern CPUs, as result it usually 10x times faster than native implementation or 20x-60x times faster than any managed implementation.